# How do I find out what Python libraries are installed on my Mac?

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python, and have found out that I can import various libraries. How do I find out what libraries exist on my Mac that I can import? How do I find out what functions they include?

I seem to remember using some web server type thing to browse through local help files, but I may have imagined that!

Comment: Did you look in your Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework directory?  What dod you see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the web server, you can run the `pydoc` module that is included in the python distribution as a script:

```
python /path/to/pydoc.py -p 1234
```

where `1234` is the port you want the server to run at. You can then visit `http://localhost:1234/` and browse the documentation.

Answer (score 39):

From the Python REPL (the command-line interpreter / Read-Eval-Print-Loop), type `help("modules")` to see a list of all your available libs.

Then to see functions within a module, do `help("posix")`, for example.  If you haven't `import`ed the library yet, you have to put quotes around the library's name.

Comment: Good news is that you will prob get that badge for being voted loads higher than the accepted answer! Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: The accepted answer taught me something new too, so it's all good :)

Comment: That's OK then! Did feel a pang of guilt!

Answer (score 3):

Every standard python distribution has [these](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) libraries, which cover most of what you will need in a project.

In case you need to find out if a library exists at runtime, you do it like this

```
try:
    import ObscureModule
except ImportError:
    print "you need to install ObscureModule"
    sys.exit(1) # or something like that
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install another library: yolk.

yolk is a python package manager and will show you everything you have added via pypi. But it will also show you site-packages added through whatever local package manager you run.

Answer (score 3):

just run the Python interpeter and type the command
import "lib_name" 
if it gives an error, you don't have the lib installed...else you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

On Leopard, depending on the python package you're using and the version number, the modules can be found in /Library/Python:

/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages

or in /Library/Frameworks

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.6/site-packages

(it could also be 3.0 or whatever version)...
I guess it is quite the same with Tiger

Answer (score 2):

Considering that in every operating system most of python's packages are installed using 'pip' (see [pip documentation](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/)) you can also use the command ***'pip freeze'*** on a terminal to print a list of all the packages you have installed through it. 
Other tools like 'homebrew' for macOS (used when for some reason you can't install a package using pip) have similar commands, in this specific case ***'brew list'***.