# How do I get a list of python libraries I've installed?

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to python, and I installed so many libraries, so I forgot what I installed and not.
I'd like to get a list of libraries I've installed. Any help would be grateful.

I'm using mac OS 10.9.2

Comment: Hi Jeong! Please take a moment to search the site for existing questions before opening a new one :)

Comment: Thank you but I've installed using easy_install, pip and setup.py

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Python > IDLE (Python GUI) and type this:

```
help('modules')
```

The others has given some links for the answers as well

Comment: @JeongMinu - Great to know that. Do remember to pick an answer so they can close this thread. You can look here too for Mac machines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055443/how-do-i-find-out-what-python-libraries-are-installed-on-my-mac

Comment: How do find out for other IDEs like Jupyter?

Comment: @MSIS You can type 'pip freeze' or 'pip list' into the Jupyter cell. You will get a list of packages including the version. The command 'pip list' gives you a nicer format for the packages and version. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939975/how-to-list-all-installed-packages-and-their-versions-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip list` or install `yolk` with `pip install yolk` and then `yolk -l`.